# How to run driver.executeScript() after an event is listened in Selenium Node js?

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, event-handling

This is the code I am trying, But it is giving content is not defined. I want to run the second executeScript() function after the event has been listened.

```js
driver.getWindowHandle().then(function(window){
driver.executeScript(function(){
  window.addEventListener('customEvent', function(e){
     console.log(content = e.detail);
      //return content['data'];
    })
 }).then(function(){
   driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20000);
    driver.executeScript("return content['data']").then(function(val){
     console.log(val);
    })
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to wait until the event has been fired. But it is impossible to do that because Selenium can't listen to events in web browser.

What you can do is to modify the event listener to write something to the web app. Then use Selenium to wait for it.

My code below add an event listener to listen to the event `customEvent` and then print the value immediately. It will print `null`.

When the event has been fired, it will assign the event value to a global value `window.content`.

Then I use `driver.wait` to check value of `window.content`. After it waited for 1000 cycles, I dispatch the `customEvent`. You can see that the wait will stop immediately after the event has been dispatched. Finally, I read the `window.content` value and print it.

```
driver.getWindowHandle().then(function(window){
    driver.executeScript(function(){
        window.addEventListener('customEvent', function(e){
            window.content = e.detail;
        });
    }).then(function(){
        driver.executeScript("return window.content['data']").then(function(val){
            console.log("Initial result from event: " + val);
        });
    });
});


var counter = 0;
driver.wait(()=> {
    console.log(counter);
    if(counter++ === 1000) {
        driver.executeScript(()=>{
            var event = new CustomEvent("customEvent", {
              detail: {
                data: "TEST Data from custom event"
              }
            });

            window.dispatchEvent(event);
        });
    }

    return driver.executeScript('return typeof window.content["data"] !== "undefined"');
});

driver.executeScript('return window.content["data"]').then((val)=>{
    console.log("Result from event: " + val);
});
```